# How upgrade a jar file dependency within the Python 3.9 PySpark package?

Tags: python, pyspark, pip, jar, log4j

How can I upgrade a jar file within a python package? I need to upgrade to the latest version of log4j within pyspark.

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/jars/log4j-1.2.17.jar`

I tried upgrading PySpark with the below since I have multiple Python versions installed. I am a novice with managing Python installations. Any pointers? Thanks.

`python3.9 -m pip install pyspark --upgrade`

(On MacOS)

Comment: What is your current `pyspark` version and what happened when you tried to upgrade it through `pip`?

Comment: The PySpark version is 3.2.1. The pip upgrade appeared to upgrade the version of PySpark without updating the dependency on log4j (stays at 1.2.17). Anything else I should check? Can I just delete the jar file and put the newer version in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the latest version of pyspark (3.2.1 from 26th January 2022) ships with `log4j-1.2.17.jar`, i.e. it is directly bundled in the `tar.gz` that pip downloads and then extracts and installs. As such, it cannot be upgraded individually, i.e. there is no automated way.

You **might** be able to simply replace the `.jar` file manually, but I would suspect that you might run into issues when the API of the newer version is different than the `1.2.17` one. I would suspect that if a newer version was compatible, the devs of the package would probably have used it

Comment: Not the answers I wanted, just the way it is I suppose. Thank you.